# Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied with NAN values

Tags: r, date, r-caret, lubridate

I have a dataset like this

```
library(lubridate)
df = data.frame(a= dmy(c('10.11.2017', '11.10.2017', '11.10.2017')), 
                b = dmy(c('10.10.2017', NaN, '11.10.2017')), c=c(1,2, 3))
```

I have to get a new variable

```
df$d = as.numeric(df$a-df$b)
```

and then to make some preprocessing with caret

```
library(caret)
trans = preProcess(df[, c('c','d')], method = c("BoxCox", "medianImpute"))
```

Error is on the next step

```
dfTrans = predict(trans, df)
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

The problem is in `NaN` value. when we do not have `NaN` all ok. 
I tried to solved as below

```
df$a = as.Date(df$a, origin="1970-01-01")
df$b = as.Date(df$b, origin="1970-01-01")
```

or

```
df$d = as.numeric(df$a-df$b, origin="1970-01-01")
```

but the error remains. Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe, you should skip rows, there some of date has Nan value, and create a dataframe without that rows?

Comment: it.s good idea but i cann't make it in the real dataset

Comment: You can't make it because you don't know how, or you can't make it, because you have to preserve all the data, even in the rows, there NaN's are present?

Comment: @Edward shouldn't you apply `predict` on data set with the same variables i.e. `c('c','d')`?

Comment: @Prem sorry I didn't understand could you explain?

Comment: `?preProcess` states that _"Pre-processing transformation (centering, scaling etc.) can be estimated from the training data and applied to any data set with the same variables."_. So your `predict` statement should be like `dfTrans = predict(trans, df[, c('c','d')])`

Comment: @Prem thanks! it works but I donn't understand why(

Comment: It means that when you train a model (i.e. `preProcess` step) based on selected features (i.e. column `c` & `d` in this case) then while predicting with new data (i.e. `predict` step) you need to give the new dataset (or the same dataset as you have given in this case) with exactly same set of features. Only the data values changes not the number of features.

Comment: @Prem I agree with you but without NaN `dfTrans = predict(trans, df)` works

Comment: Because `predict` thinks that it need to apply `medianImpute` on `a` & `b` as well when it encounters `NaN` but fails miserably as it's a date column and not a numeric so is the error `Error in as.Date.numeric(value)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Prem

The solve

```
df = data.frame(a= dmy(c('10.11.2017', '11.10.2017', '11.10.2017')), 
                b = dmy(c('10.10.2017', NaN, '11.10.2017')), c=c(1,2, 3), d=c(1,2, 3), f=c(1,NaN, 3))

df$g = as.numeric(df$a-df$b)
```

We must make Date variable as factor

```
df$b = as.factor(df$b) 
trans = preProcess(df[, c('c','d')], method = c("BoxCox", "medianImpute")) 
dfTrans = predict(trans, df)
> dfTrans
           a          b         c         d  f  g
1 2017-11-10 2017-10-10 0.0000000 0.0000000  1 31
2 2017-10-11       <NA> 0.8595276 0.8595276 NA NA
3 2017-10-11 2017-10-11 1.5553034 1.5553034  3  0
```

We can see trans is just for `c('c','d')`